# Use case for private changes

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

Supposing I have following scenario: I cloned some open-source project, say from URL X. Now I have local clone of it. I made some changes to local clone to try things out and commited them locally. Now what I want is following:

I want to get update from the open-source project X. Just get all its latest code, without my changes at all. But I want my changes to live somewhere in tag in history so I can get them later. And I don't want to separate clone for this, want it all in my one repo.

For now I did following:

1. Tag my changes with `hg tag`
2. Pull & merge latest code from URL X
3. Revert repository to latest revision of URL X

But I feel this isn't good way and it's roundabout. I think there's better way. Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of tags, I would use a [bookmark](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BookmarksExtension). If you use Mercurial 1.8 or later, you already have the bookmark functionality built-in. Otherwise, you first have enable the extension by putting the following in your `~/.hgrc` file:

```
[extensions]
bookmarks =

[bookmarks]
track.current = True
```

Now get the clone of your project:

```
hg clone http://bitbucket.org/user/X
cd X
```

and hack away:

```
# edit, edit, edit...
hg commit -m 'Great new feature!'
```

Now put a bookmark on this changeset

```
hg bookmark mywork
```

This is like a tag, but the advantage of a bookmark is that is moves along when you make new commits. This is just like when you're reading a book and move the bookmark along with you. When the bookmark is created, you can do

```
hg update mywork
```

to get back to the bookmarked changeset.

When there has been changes made in the upstream repository, then you pull and merge them into your own branch:

```
hg update mywork # if necessary
hg pull
hg merge
hg commit -m 'Merged new upstream changes.'
```

The bookmark will have moved forward and is now pointing to the merge changeset you just created. If you want to update to the version in X, then

```
hg update --rev -2
```

will do it after you pulled in changes -- this updates to the old tip changeset from before the merge, which was the tip of X.

Comment: Thank you, but bookmark is just improved tag here, right? I mean, maybe what I was looking for it is hg update --rev? instead of revert?

Comment: zaharpopov: oh, I read your "Revert repository to latest revision of URL X" as meaning `hg update` with the latest revision of X. Please read the help for both commands -- the short version is that `hg update` updates file content *and* changes the working copy parent revision whereas `hg revert` only updates files.