# How to keep a file private to a Mercurial repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I like to keep a file with some private data (links, etc) in the project that I'm working on. I liked to be versioned but not exportable (by push) to other repository.

Below is a more schematic description of my problem.

1. I cloned a repository (r) to my repository (m)
2. I added a file to my repository (m) that I do not want to push to initial repository (r) but I want it tracked in my repository (m). It's a file where I keep links, etc.
3. How can I push to initial repository (r) but ignoring the file from my repository (m)?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163591/use-case-for-mercurial-private-changes should fits perfectly your need.

Comment: @VonC: I agree, the question you linked cover the same ground. It could perhaps be rephrased more to emphasize keeping a file private, but it's the same overall problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial pushes changesets, not files.

If you ask Mercurial to start tracking a file by adding it, and then committing it, it is now part of the history of the repository.

Pushing from this repository, will push that file as well.

Summary: Don't do it, it can't be done. Find a different way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension)

Just store *creating file with all private content in mq-patch* (or only private data in patch and file-skeleton in repo)

Comment: IMO, using mercurial queues is too much hassle for this kind of problem. E.g. it's difficult to edit normal and private files at the same time.

Comment: @Lazy Badger Can you provide a small example? I read about queue but I'm still in the dark on my problem.....

Comment: @daniel-kullmann- MQ isn't easy part, but extremely usable for OP-situation and task

Comment: @Alex - I'll try to collect test-output from CLI - I use TortoiseHG with MQ most time

Comment: @LazyBadger take this as example: you have two patches, private.patch for private files, and work.patch for other changes. Then you edit both normal and private files. how do you update patches? First, update work.patch with all files, except private files. then create temp.patch with the changes to private files. qpop 2 times, so private.patch is the current patch. qfold temp.patch into private patch. qpush to work on work.patch again. I find this process inconvenient and error-prone. Maybe it is easier when using tortoisehg, though (I'm almost always using command line).

Comment: @daniel-kullmann - at least with less amount of frictions: 1. qpop local- 2. Update path 3. qpush 4. qpop --move 5. update sharedhacks- 6. qpush -all (for sake) 7. Commit. Viola! And in GUI it seems as more easier task than in written guide

Comment: @LazyBadger hmmm, I still think it's cumbersome, but the pseudo-subrepo solution also has its problems. I do think the best is to have the files in a separate repository

Comment: @daniel-kullmann - I use this techique for supporting two slightly different sites on common codebase. Two patches in MQ over common code - and single repo with single "main" branch, two exports instead of one

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new repository in your m repository, and put all your files into that. mercurial ignores repositories inside repositories, unless you include them via the subrepo extension.

```
cd m
hg init local
cd local
echo "my stuff" > info.txt
cd ..
hg st
# does not show files in local
cd local
hg ci -A -m "first commit"
cd ..
hg log -l 2
# does not show commit in local
```

A better solution in my opinion is to create a repository that lives besides the m repository. It's cleaner and more difficult to mess it up.

Comment: From what I understand that "local" repository will exist only on that machine as it can not be pushed to m remote location. Is that right?

Comment: It can be pushed to a different remote location

Comment: subrepos aren't nicest part in mercurial and have a lot of limitation

Comment: @lazybadger but this is not a subrepo

Comment: @daniel-kullmann - I can predict future: enclosed repo have good chance become subrepo rather fast (as fast as more than 1 workplace will appear)